# How do I project an image on to another image with homography

Tags: python, opencv

I have a python program that detects a rectangle from the the captured Video. Now I want to project another image into the detected square (just like in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R9mvvylyUY0)).

I have Tried using the `warpPerspective` and that does not seem to be working or maybe I'm using it in the wrong way.

my present output looks [like this](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Aj7tODivwNi97GcA-iSKDsUvfqtV). I want my output to look [like this](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Aj7tODivwNi97GjBtocEcdPCatYN)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tried to overlay images after using `warpPerspective`:

```
img = cv2.imread('cola.jpg')
img = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
background = cv2.imread('stadium.jpg')
background = cv2.cvtColor(background,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

rows,cols,ch = background.shape

pts1 = np.float32([[0,0],[974,0],[0,974],[974,974]]) # cola coords 
pts2 = np.float32([[560,383],[940, 516],[5,527],[298,733]]) # stadium tile coords

M = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(pts1,pts2)    
dst = cv2.warpPerspective(img,M,(cols,rows))

overlay = cv2.add(background, dst)
```

[Output image

[image: Output image]

I used OpenCV [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/da/d6e/tutorial_py_geometric_transformations.html)